# how to use q promise 2.X with requirejs on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, q

This

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: { 
    'q' : '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/2.0.3/q.min'
}});

require(['q'], function(Q) {
  console.log("In Loaded callback");
  console.log("Q: %o", Q);
  return {};
});
```

fails with:

```
Module name "weak-map" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
File: require.min.js, Line: 1, Column: 1948
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maccullt/4jmoarps)

However, this works fine:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: { 
    'q' : '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.4.1/q.min'
}});
```

Comment: Apparently Q 2.x relies on `WeakMap`s, which are not available in most browsers natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked and found out that Q v2 is experimental now. In source code we can see that it has dependency with following library

```
var WeakMap = require("weak-map");
var iterate = require("pop-iterate");
var asap = require("asap");
```

And this type of require/module import is for node/browserify. It wont support require.js. As per documentation:-

> This is Q version 2 and is experimental at this time. If you install the latest Q from npm, you will get the latest from the version 1 release train.

So it is better to stick to v1 at this point of time unless we are using it in nodejs/browserify.